# Best practices for designing databases with addresses

Tags: database, database-design

I was studying a design case in which they discuss how to deal with the design of the database of a system that is already under development. The system is for for managing public parking. The main debate is how to meet the following requirements:

1. The system shall allow managing information of each parking company.
2. The data stored is the parking lot's adress (details, province, county, district), name, corporate identification, number of spaces.
3. The system should handle reports of the revenue generated by each parking.

These reports should allow filtering by province, as the company has several parking by province, some of them located in the same district.

Some people have mentioned that the table ParkingLot must have the colums for province, county and district, and which are characteristic of each parking.

Others say it should not be. I was wondering which was the best way to approach the design of the database in this specific point.
Which boils down to my questions, in this type of cases (because there must be exeptions) where the system is pretty straight forward, does it really matter?

What if these reports should allow filtering by province? As a company could have several parking lots in the same province, some of them located in the same district.

Comment: Is a district always within a county and is a county always within a province?  Or can they overlap in weird ways?

Comment: @WW. A province has more than one county and a county has more than one district, always in that order. For example you cannot have Province, Country, District, County.

Comment: Beware, the city and county of San Francisco in California has one city in the county.  It isn't clear whether California's a province within your terms of reference; it sounds a bit as if you might be working in Canada.  Do you have to worry about international address structures?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I lack enought geographical knowledge but I assume the case meant that a Province can have one or more Conties which in turn could have one or more districts. Also it seems to pertain to only 'local' addresses, that is to say no international structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you need to decide what to model.

**Option 1 - Columns on ParkingLot**

If you add columns for `province`, `county` and `district` to the `ParkingLot` table, then you are modelling that each parking lot has these things.

Your model in this case does not include a master list of districts, county and provinces.  You would not be able to validate that the details entered for a particular lot was valid.

Choose this option if you obtain the parking lots from a trusted source or you district, etc.  This option doesn't allow you to store any additional information. e.g. if you need to store a "area manager" against a particular region you would have nowhere to store it.

**Option 2 - Model Districts, County and Provinces**

You could create tables for `province`, `county` and `district`.  These would have foreign keys to their parents.  In this case you do have a master list (which you need to keep up to date).

Then on each parking lot you have a foreign key to the `district` (which implies the other columns).

Choose this option if you want to validate district, etc. against a master list.  Also choose this if you have extra information to store against `district`, etc.

Comment: Perfectly explained the difference between the two! Thanks a lot for the insight, I'll keep them in mind.